# CkEditor - how to change the look

Tags: ckeditor

I'm a pretty newbe at html, css, etc. etc.
I just downloaded the CkEditor and it works perfect. I use the inline editor replacing a textarea. Now I would like to change the look a bit

a) I would like to have the editable area with a different background color

b) I would like to have a thin line around the area

How can I do this? As far as I understood I need to manually change that in one of the css files - but where, and what do I need to put in there?

ALso I tried to configure the toolbar using the configuration tool and although I opted for the button "source-code" it won't show up? How can I manually include this in the toolbar?

Sorry, I know that these are very basic questions and I tried to search for answers on the forum (but the only things I found where some years old, and trying to duplicate what was posted didn't work... - guess it changed with the new version of ckeditor).

Comment: Ok,for those who have the same problem regarding Inline Editor: here the simple solution (took me a while to find the right page - overlooked it before) In your main page website in the css file add a class and in there the format you want - in my case background color and border. Then simply put your textareas which will be replaced for inline editing within a <div class='whatyounamedit'><textarea id='number'></textarea></div> and voila the problem is solved. As the inline editor won't take formatting from the ckeditor css but takes it directly from the main site css!

Comment: Regarding the source code button: Inline editor apparently doesn't offer the possibility for source code editing....